# ADO Recordset Batch Insert HAS NO Advantage against Regular insert

Tags: sql-server, database, ado, batch-processing, bulkinsert

I'm using ADO to insert records into a database..

Reading the documentation, I found out that ADO Recordset object has Batch/Bulk insert functionality.[link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In theory, batch/bulk insert should perform many times better than regular insert when dealing with many rows of data.. and this performance difference is testified in an interesting [blog post](http://venzi.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/loading-data-fast-regular-insert-vs-bulk-insert/):

So this is how I implemented the Bulk insert using ADO:

```
class MyRecord : public CADORecordBinding {
    BEEGIN_ADO_BINDING(MyRecord)

    ADO_VARIABLE_LENGTH_ENTRY2(1, adInteger, m_value, sizeof(m_value1), m_status1, TRUE)

    END_ADO_BINDING()

public:
    INT m_value1;
    ULONG m_status1;
}


void BatchInsert() {
    _RecordsetPtr RecPtr = NULL;
    RecPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
    RecPtr->Open("MY_TABLE_NAME", MY_CONNECTION_STRING, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable);


    IADORecordBinding *Binding = NULL;
    MyRecord Record;

    RecPtr->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IADORecordBinding), (LPVOID*)&Binding);
    Binding->BindToRecordset(&Record);
    Record.m_value = 99999999;

    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        Binding->AddNew(&Record);
    }

    RecPtr.UpdateBatch(adAffectAll);

    RecPtr->Close();
}
```

At least the Bulk insert seems to work fine (Until the "UpdateBatch()" method is called, the actual database is NOT modified.. In other words, it is only after UpdateBatch is called when the batch of 10000 insert statements are called)..
If I DON'T use the Batch Insert functionality, by setting "adLockOptimistic" instead of "adLockBatchOptimistic", and refresh my database every second, I can visually see the records populating the database one at a time..

The problem is, however, when I test the performances, there is ALMOST NO difference between Batch inset and Normal insert!!

This is the average time it took to insert 10000 rows of data:

```
Normal Insert = 11.016 seconds
Batch Insert = 10.841 seconds
```

According to the Blog Post I referenced above, batch insert was almost 100 times faster than the normal insert!! My result, however, tells me that there is almost no difference in performance..

Is this simply because ADO's Batch Update function sucks??

The Batch Insert works as it is supposed to,, and I can't think of any other way I can implement this..

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: I think the advantage is less speed and more that you are wrapping your inserts in a transaction.

Comment: @Brad Hm.. what would be the advantage of that, simply wrapping instructions?? And the blog post I referenced above says something different

Comment: The Venzi's Tech-Blog you referenced is an article about Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: The blog post doesn't seem to talk about ADO and is not about Sql Server. `UpdateBatch()` is basically like calling `commit trans` in sql server. You can do all your inserts but they are not committed until you tell them to be. This is a very powerful data integrity tool.

Comment: @Brad Yes, I see that.. But isn't the concept of bulk insert the same for all databases? If bulk insert can be 100 times faster in Oracle, but not in Sql Server,, does that mean Oracle is superior over Sql Server.

Comment: I would imagine the concept is the same, yes.  The Oracle vs Sql Server stuff is just troll bait.

Comment: To add to what @Brad posted, you could start by ensuring that the 10k inserts are wrapped in a single transaction, as opposed to 10k transactions (one per insert).  If you want to get more granular than that, you could change the recovery model from FULL to BULK LOGGED.  Other options include disabling indexes and table constraints, then rebuilding indexes and re-enabling constraints after the bulk load.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx) for more details on optimizing bulk transactions.

Comment: Saying "Bulk Insert" is something very specific in Sql Server. I don't know Oracle well but on the MS side this implies you are reading in a file into your database. it is formatted like your table. You seem to be talking about Batch inserts through an ADO provider, which again. might be different based on if ADO is talking to Sql Server or Oracle, but I understand these are transactioned inserts. Bulk <> Batch (not necessarily ==) transaction

Comment: @Brad Thanks. So in SQL SERVER,, Bulk Insert (which you said is very specific to sql server) does not give much advantage in terms of speed, right? It just lets you wrap the statements..

Comment: I'm not saying that it is specific to Sql Server but is means something specific in Sql Server and might not mean the same thing else where.

Comment: Ultimately: check what DB your connecting to. Check how you are opening your connection. What do you want to accomplish? How is your table indexed? Is the speed bottle neck ADO, the database, your connection? There are a lot of unknowns and it is hard to make a definitive statement that "ADO Recordset Batch Insert HAS NO Advantage against Regular insert". Ado has been around for a long time. Everything in it exists for a reason and has an advantage in a situation.